# Eclipse Oxigen, no guarda cambios en mi proyecto | al eliminar o crear servlets no refleja cambios

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Tengo un proyecto web, que estoy desarrollando en un entorno de Eclipse Oxygen 3, y desde hace un par de días
que el proyecto, no hace cambios (por ejemplo:)
Tengo en mi proyecto web dinámico, algunos servlets y JSP, pero cuando hago cambios en los servlets
no me muestra los cambios o modificaciones de dichos servlets, como si se tratara de una versión
anterior de mi proyecto, 
también eliminé algunos servlets, (aparentemente se eliminaron), pero todavía el proyecto los 
lee como si estubíeran en el proyecto.
otro ejemplo:
cuando creo servlets nuevos (aparentemente se crean), pero cuando los mando a llamar en alguna 
función no existen, (como si nunca los hubiera creado).

entonces Mi proyecto se encuentra en una versión anterior, y todo lo que he modificado no se refleja.

ojo: ya borré la cache del navegador
ojo: si se ven los cambios de los javascripts y JSP. pero los servlets no!!

Que puede generar ese problema?
como puedo solucionarlo?
Ayuda por favor, soy nuevo en esto de eclipse!

Answer (score 0):

A mi me paso un problema similar con `glassfish`, funcionaban los `servlets` y los `JSP` no lo hacían. Mi aplicación funcionaba con `java 1.5` y el `glassfish` me parece que era el `4`. Así que que el `glassfish` tambien apuntaba a `java 1.5`. Y resulto que ese era el problema: `glassfish` necesitaba `java 1.6` para funcionar bien. Entonces apunte `glassfish` a `java 1.6` y después apunte mi aplicación a `java 1.5`. Solo así logro funcionar.

Te recomiendo que revises las versiones de `java` a la cual apunta tu `eclipse` y también te recomiendo usar otro `workspace`.

Comment: Gracias!, daré seguimiento a tus recomendaciones !.

Comment: Tengo la 4.1.1.